# Background Image Problems

Tags: html, css

I am pretty fresh to development and have been trying to work together a little portfolio page but have been having trouble with a background image for my body section. I have been trying to look for possible solutions online have have come across many answers all of which aren't doing anything.

[My CodePen](https://codepen.io/mikebly/pen/VQgReW) shows that back-ground image is pushing the footer to the top of the page, and has this gap at the bottom. The footer is out of the div with the image so I am not sure why it is hoping to the top of the page. I have also tried all sorts of combinations of setting heights and minimum heights to 100%, but the image is not taking the height of its parent div.

Thank you in advance if this is something simple I am overlooking :)

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0px;
  height: 100%;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #777;
  padding:0;
  min-height:100%;
}

.bg-img {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/574073/pexels-photo-574073.jpeg");
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
}
.nav-name {
  font-family: garamond;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#stuff {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: garamond;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-btn {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  padding:5px 15px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  background-color:#afeab4;
}

.about-wrapper {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 35px 0px 35px 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.about-text {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.skills ul {
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-stlye: italic;
}

.about-pic {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.about-img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid white;
}

.portfolio-title {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
}

.portfolio-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 5px;
}

.portfolio-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: #6fc676;
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.card-name {
  text-align:center;
}
#card1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card4 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

.contact-title {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0px;
}

.contact-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.contact-form {
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#contact input,
textarea {
  background: transparent;
  margin:3px;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submit {
  text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: #888;
  opactity: 0.9;
}

.contact-links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.link1 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link2 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link3 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link4 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #6fc676;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.fa-facebook:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #6fc676;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-github {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6fc676;
}

.fa-github:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-free-code-camp {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fa-free-code-camp:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

footer {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Mojo Design</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="stuff">
        <h3 class="nav-name">Michael Blydenburgh</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#about">About</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></button></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


<div class ="bg-img">
    <div class="about-wrapper" id="about">

      <div class="about-text">
        I am a classically trained chemical engineer hoping to take my career in a new direction. Current experience is in front-end development, with basic server side knowledge and a desire to continue professional growth. Please feel free to contact me to
        discuss what assistance you are looking for!
      </div>
      <div class="about-pic">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1780363/mike.jpg" alt="Self Photograph" class="about-img">
      </div>
      <div class="skills">
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>Javascript</li>
          <li>Python</li>
          <li>PHP</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="portfolio-title">Portfolio</h3>
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper" id="portfolio">
      <div class="card" id="card1">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1780363/tribute.JPG" alt="Page Preview" class="portfolio-img">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Tribute to Umphreys McGee</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card2">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page2</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card3">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page3</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card4">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page4</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="contact-title">Contact & Social Media</h3>
    <div class="contact-wrapper" id="contact">

      <div class="contact-form">
        <form action="http:///www.example.com/contact.php">
          <fieldset>
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="40" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="100" id="name-form">
          </label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="40" placeholder="Enter Email" maxlength="100" id="email-form">
          </label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" class="message-form">Leave a message!</textarea>
          </label>
            <div class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit Message" id="submit-btn">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-links">
        <div class="link1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mblydenburgh" class="fa fa-facebook" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link2"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-blydenburgh-99a68872/" class="fa fa-linkedin" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link3"><a href="https://github.com/mikebly" class="fa fa-github" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link4"><a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/mikebly" class="fa fa-free-code-camp" target="blank"></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>


</div>


  <footer>
  Design and Coded by Michael Blydenburgh (2018)
  </footer>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `bg-img` class' `position: absolute;` value.

An element with `position: absolute;` is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed).

so, i changed it to `relative` which positioned relative to the current position of the element.

Check this link also [css_positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0px;
  height: 100%;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #777;
  padding:0;
  min-height:100%;
}

.bg-img {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/574073/pexels-photo-574073.jpeg");
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
}
.nav-name {
  font-family: garamond;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#stuff {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: garamond;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-btn {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  padding:5px 15px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  background-color:#afeab4;
}

.about-wrapper {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 35px 0px 35px 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.about-text {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.skills ul {
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-stlye: italic;
}

.about-pic {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.about-img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid white;
}

.portfolio-title {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
}

.portfolio-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 5px;
}

.portfolio-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: #6fc676;
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.card-name {
  text-align:center;
}
#card1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card4 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

.contact-title {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0px;
}

.contact-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.contact-form {
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#contact input,
textarea {
  background: transparent;
  margin:3px;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submit {
  text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: #888;
  opactity: 0.9;
}

.contact-links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.link1 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link2 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link3 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link4 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #6fc676;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.fa-facebook:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #6fc676;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-github {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6fc676;
}

.fa-github:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-free-code-camp {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fa-free-code-camp:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

footer {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Mojo Design</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="stuff">
        <h3 class="nav-name">Michael Blydenburgh</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#about">About</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></button></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

<section>
<div class ="bg-img">
    <div class="about-wrapper" id="about">

      <div class="about-text">
        I am a classically trained chemical engineer hoping to take my career in a new direction. Current experience is in front-end development, with basic server side knowledge and a desire to continue professional growth. Please feel free to contact me to
        discuss what assistance you are looking for!
      </div>
      <div class="about-pic">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1780363/mike.jpg" alt="Self Photograph" class="about-img">
      </div>
      <div class="skills">
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>Javascript</li>
          <li>Python</li>
          <li>PHP</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="portfolio-title">Portfolio</h3>
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper" id="portfolio">
      <div class="card" id="card1">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1780363/tribute.JPG" alt="Page Preview" class="portfolio-img">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Tribute to Umphreys McGee</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card2">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page2</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card3">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page3</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card4">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page4</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="contact-title">Contact & Social Media</h3>
    <div class="contact-wrapper" id="contact">

      <div class="contact-form">
        <form action="http:///www.example.com/contact.php">
          <fieldset>
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="40" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="100" id="name-form">
          </label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="40" placeholder="Enter Email" maxlength="100" id="email-form">
          </label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" class="message-form">Leave a message!</textarea>
          </label>
            <div class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit Message" id="submit-btn">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-links">
        <div class="link1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mblydenburgh" class="fa fa-facebook" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link2"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-blydenburgh-99a68872/" class="fa fa-linkedin" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link3"><a href="https://github.com/mikebly" class="fa fa-github" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link4"><a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/mikebly" class="fa fa-free-code-camp" target="blank"></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>


</div>
</section>

  <footer>
  Design and Coded by Michael Blydenburgh (2018)
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Changing the position to relative made it so I could not click on the links or form boxes, so I made a parent div and set it to inherit. The links are clickable again, but the positioning of the footer is still not quite right and overlapping part of the submit and social media buttons. Some positioning that I am not accounting for?

Comment: @MikeBlydenburgh I set `z-index` to `1` and now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. I had inserted `padding-top: 146px` in the style of the `.bg-img`. I had used the value 146px because the height of the div is 146px.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin:0px;
  height: 100%;
}


body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #777;
  padding:0;
  min-height:100%;
}

.bg-img {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/574073/pexels-photo-574073.jpeg");
  position: absolute;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding-top: 146px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
}
.nav-name {
  font-family: garamond;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
}

header::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#stuff {
  margin: 0px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
}

nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: garamond;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-btn {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  padding:5px 15px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.nav-btn:hover {
  background-color:#afeab4;
}

.about-wrapper {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  padding: 35px 0px 35px 5px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.about-text {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.skills ul {
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-stlye: italic;
}

.about-pic {
  justify-self: center;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.about-img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border:2px solid white;
}

.portfolio-title {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
}

.portfolio-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 5px;
}

.portfolio-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.card {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: #6fc676;
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.card-name {
  text-align:center;
}
#card1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

#card4 {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 2px #888888;
}

.contact-title {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: black;
  font-family: garamond;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0px;
}

.contact-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.contact-form {
  margin: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#contact input,
textarea {
  background: transparent;
  margin:3px;
}

::placeholder {
  /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: black;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submit {
  text-align: center;
}

#submit-btn {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

#submit-btn:hover {
  background-color: #888;
  opactity: 0.9;
}

.contact-links {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

.link1 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link2 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link3 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.link4 {
  margin: 0px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #6fc676;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.fa-facebook:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #6fc676;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-github {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #6fc676;
}

.fa-github:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

.fa-free-code-camp {
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.fa-free-code-camp:hover{
  background:#a2e8ae;
}

footer {
  background-color: #6fc676;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 0px 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Mojo Design</title>
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
      <div id="stuff">
        <h3 class="nav-name">Michael Blydenburgh</h3>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#about">About</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></button></li>
            <li><button class="nav-btn"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></button></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>


<div class ="bg-img">
    <div class="about-wrapper" id="about">

      <div class="about-text">
        I am a classically trained chemical engineer hoping to take my career in a new direction. Current experience is in front-end development, with basic server side knowledge and a desire to continue professional growth. Please feel free to contact me to
        discuss what assistance you are looking for!
      </div>
      <div class="about-pic">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1780363/mike.jpg" alt="Self Photograph" class="about-img">
      </div>
      <div class="skills">
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>HTML</li>
          <li>CSS</li>
          <li>Javascript</li>
          <li>Python</li>
          <li>PHP</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="portfolio-title">Portfolio</h3>
    <div class="portfolio-wrapper" id="portfolio">
      <div class="card" id="card1">
        <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1780363/tribute.JPG" alt="Page Preview" class="portfolio-img">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Tribute to Umphreys McGee</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card2">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page2</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card3">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page3</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card4">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h5>Page4</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h3 class="contact-title">Contact & Social Media</h3>
    <div class="contact-wrapper" id="contact">

      <div class="contact-form">
        <form action="http:///www.example.com/contact.php">
          <fieldset>
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="40" placeholder="Enter Name" maxlength="100" id="name-form">
          </label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="40" placeholder="Enter Email" maxlength="100" id="email-form">
          </label>
            <br>
            <label>
            <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" class="message-form">Leave a message!</textarea>
          </label>
            <div class="submit">
              <input type="submit" value="Submit Message" id="submit-btn">
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="contact-links">
        <div class="link1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/mblydenburgh" class="fa fa-facebook" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link2"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/michael-blydenburgh-99a68872/" class="fa fa-linkedin" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link3"><a href="https://github.com/mikebly" class="fa fa-github" target="blank"></a></div>
        <div class="link4"><a href="https://www.freecodecamp.org/mikebly" class="fa fa-free-code-camp" target="blank"></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>


</div>


  <footer>
  Design and Coded by Michael Blydenburgh (2018)
  </footer>

</body>
```